# Nginx redirect for menu items in application

Tags: nginx

So have an Nginx server called proxy1 which is supposed to redirect to two applications (app1 and app2).

For the first proxy_pass I use:

```
 server {
     listen 80;

     server_name proxy1;

     location /app1 {
     proxy_pass http://host1:9090/admin;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
```

This directs me to the app1 admin page which has some url options

When I hover over them i see they are:

```
http://proxy1/admin/metrics?pretty=true
http://proxy1/admin/ping
http://proxy1/admin/threads
http://proxy1/admin/healthcheck?pretty=true
```

How can I configure Nginx to redirect these menu urls to the correct app (app1)?

Comment: It's your application that produces such urls. You should check the code.

Comment: Thanks, not my application but I can send it back. Setting the location to /admin works but app2 has the exact same URLs.

Comment: Your error lies in specifying the `proxy_pass` with `/admin/` stuck on the url. If `admin` and `app1` is the same thing, replace app1 with admin and access it using that URI. If they are separate, you'll most likely need a rewrite statement with a separate location block.

Comment: Both applications use exactly the same URLs ./admin/* and both reside on host1 (different ports) so I used app1/app2 to differentiate between the two.